# Синхронизация 1с и MySQL на лету - как?

Tags: 1с, mysql

Есть бд 1С, надо синхронизировать её с MySQL, как это сделать?

Comment: ну как как, посмотреть что нужно выгружать в каком формате, в каком принимать и как обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например так: [тык по ссылке](http://werther.wwgroup.in.ua/2010/07/07/%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c-1%d1%81-%d1%81-mysql/)